# Where and how do the ViewLocator-generated Views get their DataContexts assigned (in Avalonia's Todo tutorial application)?

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

In the completed Avalonia tutorial Todo application --- where and how do TodoListView and AddItemView acquire their  DataContexts to be equal to TodoListViewModel and AddItemViewModel  respectively ???
I mean their parent control MainWindow's DataContext is a MainWindowViewModel instance (as assigned in App.xaml.cs file) --- while MainWindow's Content attribute is bound to MainWindowViewModel's Content property (which does get assigned instances of the viewmodels during execution). I just cannot trace the source wherefrom TodoListView and AddItemView acquire their DataContexts. Do they get it while:

1. Being created by the ViewLocator at runtime ?  --  but that's not possible as the DataContext property of the newly instantiated View is still NULL just before the ViewLocator returns the View instance -- as shown by the output of following code in the completed application (the code in the if block is modified by me to produce required output):

```
public IControl Build(object data)
        {
            var name = data.GetType().FullName.Replace("ViewModel", "View");
            var type = Type.GetType(name);

            if (type != null)
            {
                var viewInstance = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                
                // the following always evaluates to true --- i.e. DataContext is always NULL before viewInstance is returned.
                if(viewInstance.DataContext == null)   
Console.WriteLine($"DataContext property of the newly created View instance of {name} in ViewLocator is NULL just before returning! ");


                 
                return  viewInstance ;
            }
            else
            {
                return new TextBlock { Text = "Not Found: " + name };
            }
        }
```

2. OR they get their DataContext assigned by the parent Window ? --- but the parent window's own DataContext is MainWindowViewModel -----  how do we get to TodoListViewModel or AddItemViewModel  from   MainWindowViewModel ???

In short , I am unclear about where the Views generated at runtime via ViewLocator are getting their DataContext properties assigned.

---

Summarizing what I understood from the answer and some search and play:

---

If a ContentControl's (in this case Window's) Content property is a Control then the Control simply inherits the DataContext from the parent ContentControl. But if  the ContentControl's Content property is a non-Control then the ContentPresenter of the ContentControl first finds a data template for the non-Control  so that a child View can be generated and then sets its own DataContext to the non-Control. This newly assigned DataContext then gets inherited by the newly generated child View. Phewwwwww!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataContext` is inherited from `ContentPresenter` which is asking `IDataTemplate.Build` for a new view instance. When `Content` isn't a control, `ContentPresenter` [sets its own](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/794d149630cdad623f9f30d463efca1c8dce4727/src/Avalonia.Controls/Presenters/ContentPresenter.cs#L237) `DataContext` to the value of `Content` which gets inherited by the child view.

`ContentPresenter` is [used internally](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/794d149630cdad623f9f30d463efca1c8dce4727/src/Avalonia.Themes.Default/Window.xaml#L9) by the `Window` to display its `Content` property.

Same happens with `ListBox` items.

Comment: Wow -- thanks --- that was quick and to the point. Brilliant!